# Distance between a point and the diagonal set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Problem:

Given a metric space $(M,d)$ and the diagonal set $\Delta:= \{(x,x)|x\in M\}$. Show that $$z = (x,y)\notin \Delta \implies d'(z, \Delta)>0,$$

where $d'$ is a metric associated with $M\times M$.

My thoughts:

My idea is to look for a term $c$, probably dependent of $d(x,y)$, where $d'(z, \Delta)>c>0$. How to find that $c$? There's another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

$\Delta$ is a closed set because every metric space is Hausdorff.

Thus if $x_0 \in \Delta^c$ then exists $R>0$ such that $B(x_0,R) \cap \Delta=\emptyset \Longrightarrow B(x_0,R) \subset \Delta^c \Longrightarrow d'(x,y) \geq R ,\forall y \in \Delta \Longrightarrow d'(x,\Delta) \geq R$

> Also note that:
>
> $\textbf{Lemma}$ In a general metric space,if $A$ is closed and $B$ is compact then $\exists C>0$ such that $d(x,y) \geq C,\forall x \in A, \forall y \in B$

From this, with $A=\Delta$ and $B=\{x_0\}$ you have again the desired conclusion.

You can prove the lemma i mentioned as an exercise,if you want.

Comment: Sincerely, thank you very much for the answer! Saddly, we can't use topological concepts like closure or compactness yet. Some examples of concepts allowed are balls and limited sets (metric spaces where $d(x,y)$ is always less than a real number $c$.

Comment: Then  ignore the second part of the answer and pay attention at the first two lines

Comment: Alright, but how do I know that exists $R>0$ such that $B(x_{0}, R)\cap\Delta = \emptyset$ without using closure?

Comment: because the complement of a closed set is open and then we use the definition of an open set

Comment: Observe that $d(x,\Delta)=\inf\{d(x,y):y\in\Delta\}=0$, if and only if, for every $\varepsilon>0$ we have $B(x,\varepsilon)\cap\Delta=\{y\in\Delta:d(x,y)<\varepsilon\}\neq\emptyset$. So, $d(y,\Delta)>0$ implies the existence of some $r>0$ such that $B(y,r)\cap\Delta=\emptyset$. Although we haven't used "topology", it's ideias is clearly behind !

Answer (score 1):

A direct proof, without appeal to general topology (I'm assuming we're using the supremum distance, i.e. $d'((a,b),(c,d))=\max\{d(a,c),d(b,d)\}$):

Let $r=d(x,y)$ and consider $B:=B(z,\frac{r}{3})$ in $M\times M$. We claim that $B\cap \Delta=\emptyset$.

Indeed, if $(w,w)\in B,$ then both $d(w,x)<\frac{r}{3}$ and $d(w,y)<\frac{r}{3}$. In particular, $d(x,y)\leq d'((x,x),z)\leq d'((x,x),(w,w))+d'((w,w),z)< \frac{2r}{3},$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: That's the problem... we don't have any distance/metric and can't use topological concepts like closure or compactness to solve this question. With a metric it would be much easier.

Comment: The question was literally to show that a certain distance was strictly positive?

Comment: Nope... Actually, I translated the book exercise in more detail. If you want the portuguese version: Seja $\Delta = \{(, ) |  \in \}$ a diagonal do produto $ \times $ onde $$ é um espaço métrico.
Se $ = (, ) \in \Delta$ então $(, \Delta) > 0.$

Comment: So the part in the question where it reads $z=(x,y)\not\in \Delta \Longrightarrow d'(z,\Delta)>0$ is a typo?

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you mean. No, isn't a typo. We have to show that $d'(z,\Delta)$ is strictly positive or, equivalently, that for some $\epsilon>0$, any $(w,w)\in\Delta$ is such that $d'((x,y),(w,w))>\epsilon$.

Comment: So, reading on, $d'$ is a metric, and so, we have a metric. You just didn't write out what it is. I'm just assuming it's the one stated above (it's the most natural in my opinion, but running both metrics through any norm on $\mathbb{R}$ works).

Comment: And in this case, we see that $\varepsilon=\frac{d(x,y)}{3}$ works by the proof above.

Comment: Ok, if you think it's natural, I'll assume the "max metric" (I guess the author forgot to mention). Thanks!

Comment: There is a family of metrics on $M\times M$ given by $d_p((a,b),(c,d))=(d(a,c)^p+d(c,d))^{1/p}$ (with the max metric in the case of $p=\infty$), and they're all equivalent, since all norms on $\mathbb{R}$ are equivalent.